# What is the best way to invoke a onscreen keyboard when cursor placed on a wxTextCtrl?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, wxwidgets, raspbian, on-screen-keyboard, wxtextctrl

I'm trying to design a GUI touch screen application using wxWidgets(version 3.0.4). The touch screen is working fine. I need to use the on screen keyboard to populate a text box(wxTextCtrl).

I've done some searching and I dont find any `setfocus` or `getfocus` functions available for the `wxTextCtrl`. Neither can I find any event that tells that a cursor is placed in the text field so that I can invoke a onscreen keyboard.

Is there any library available or do I need to implement my own version of the keyboard?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no wx on screen keyboard. To your other questions, `wxTextCtrl` does have `SetFocus()` and [wxSetCursorEvent](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_set_cursor_event.html).

Comment: @Mano, in our application we ha have a text control and a little button next to it. Whenever the user click this button or presses it another wxWindow pops up withe button that represent the keyboard layout. It works good on wxGTK.

Comment: Yeah that was supposed to be my plan B, however it would be preferable if the on screen keyboard pops up automatically. On second thoughts, I wanted to add the `EVT_LEFT_DCLICK` event in the `EVENT_TABLE` by modifying the wxwidgets source, `textctrl.cpp` file and miserably failed to do so. Any ideas on how it can be done would be greatly helpful

Comment: After some research, I ended up using this eventhandler callback function `Connect(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, wxFocusEventHandler(DoSomethingonOnFocus), NULL, this);` in which i'm using `system("xvkbd")` to invoke an onscreen keyboard. But the problem here is, there is no feedback from `xvkbd` until it is closed. That is all the characters entered are buffered until the keyboard is closed. Once the keyboard is closed, the characters are flushed out to the window/widget that's under focus. Any better ideas to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxExecute` function did the trick. I was able to successfully get the feedback
in the wxwidget app from the key presses performed via the `xvkbd`. Sample code below:

```
this->main_frame->text_field->Connect(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS,wxFocusEventHandler(InvokeKeyboard), NULL, this);

void InvokeKeyboard(wxFocusEvent& event)
{
    event.Skip();
    system("killall xvkbd 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null");
    wxExecute(wxT("xvkbd > /dev/null 2>/dev/null"), wxEXEC_ASYNC | wxEXEC_NODISABLE | wxEXEC_HIDE_CONSOLE );
}
```

You can refer [here](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__funcmacro__procctrl.html) for the detailed documentation of `wxExecute`